# Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException: No option with :text, :label or :value in this select element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver

Watir Automation testing: I'm trying to select an option from a select box , but since the options in the select box are set dynamically I am not able to do it correctly.

Html looks like :

```
     <select id="abc">
     <option>Select</option>
     <option>First</option>
     <option>Second</option>
     <option>Third</option>
     </select>
```

The command I'm trying to use is as follows :

```
$browser.select_list(:id, "abc").select("Second").
```

Since the options are dynamically set , the above command will fail if `<option>Second</option>` does not exist in the HTML .

error :

```
Watir::Exception::NoValueFoundException: No option with :text, :label or :value in this select element
```

What's the best way to implement this?Is there any way of selection using indexes/order?

Comment: I'm using watir-ruby api

Comment: hmm in java you can select by index, value and visible text but with ruby I can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the option by index if you access the option directly.

Try:

```
$browser.select_list(:id, "abc").option(:index, 2).select
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using just the select method and adding the text attribute as seen below:

```
browser.select(:id, 'abc').option(:text, 'Second').select
```

or just

```
browser.option(:text, 'Second').select
```

Let me know how these work out for you.

Comment: The options are dynamic , an option named "Second" may or may not exist every time. Due to which I can't do browser.option(:text, 'Second').select .